# Is it possible to use Netty 3.x and 4.0 in the same app, or will there be classname conflicts?

Tags: netty

I'm evaluating the use of netty 4 for some future work, but it will have to work within our existing webapp logic which has an indirect dependency on Netty 3.x as a result of some third-party libraries we require.

I know there was significant re-factoring in netty 4.0.  As a result, I was wondering if it's possible to use both in the same application, or if there is still some overlap that would result in classname conflicts, or possibly some other [not-so-obvious] side effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible... Netty 3 use org.jboss.netty as package name and Netty 4 io.netty, so no problem at all.